# Status of D support on iOS

Tags: ios, d

What's the current status of writing apps in D on iOS? I'm not interested in using any iOS API's, just OpenGL/SDL. Is it possible to write for iOS in D at the moment? If so, how problematic is it?

Comment: If you vote to close, tell me the reason. I don't see this neither as too localized nor as not constructive (maybe the latter part, but I can remove that one)

Comment: IIRC the iOS licence forbids the use of any language other then ObjC (or JS but only in a browser). OTOH that might have been changed to something more sane in the meanwhile.

Comment: @BCS it has (fortunately) changed.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell it should be possible. You can use gcc to compile iOS apps and gcc supports D.

I've never used D myself and I've never replaced the default compiler in Xcode, but there is an option for it in build settings.

If I were you that's where I'd start. I don't know if there are any other steps needed to get it to work, but technically it shouldn't be any harder than using C++ on iOS, which I know is fairly common.

I hope this gives you an idea of how to go forward.

Answer (score 3):

LDC (the LLVM-based D compiler) can now compile D code for iOS.  Additional information can be found at http://wiki.dlang.org/LDC.

Comment: It looks like you are the author of this: https://github.com/smolt/ldc-iphone-dev (you humble person you).  And this is real, I was able to build it.  Interested in what else we need to do to move this forward.